# Cover Letter with Short Stylish Cover Letter

Tags: scrlttr2

I am using this template for the cover letter:
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/short-stylish-cover-letter

I would like to understand of to put more space between the title and the line in which there is my name and address.

Thanks a lot,
Fab.

Comment: Have you tried adding `\\[1.1cm]`? Also, [have a look at this page](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/WhiteSpace.html).

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could give a little more information on this. Does [scrlttr2 Change vertical space between sender address and email/phone](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169888) help by any chance? With some information, i bet somebody can answer this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i have to say that i do *not* recommend using the templated linked in the question. It uses obsolete options and does really weird stuff most of the time.

The `firsthead` is set within a  `parbox`, so the same rules and mechanisms as in every other LaTeX document apply.

I cleaned the code up a little bit:

```
\documentclass[symbolicnames]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 Broadway\\City\\Country}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \centering{\Huge\scshape\usekomavar{fromname}\par%
%   \vspace{1em}%<- apply space as needed
}%
    {\Large\scshape Application\par}%
}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering
{%
\renewcommand{\\}{~{\large\textperiodcentered}~}%
\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
}\\%
\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\quad\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\%
123 Pleasant Lane\\%
12345 City, State%
}

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext

\blindtext[3]
\closing{See you on monday}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```